# Best system administrators reference for managing .NET applications

Tags: untagged

We develop all our solutions in .NET. Some of the concrete technologies we use are ASP .NET MVC, WCF and Windows Services.

Our system administrators, who obviously have the responsibility on making our applications runs smooth in a hosted environment, have asked us where they can get documentation for the Microsoft technologies we use from a "system administrator perspective".

I found this page for WCF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731055.aspx

But is there any definitive source for system administrators which shows them their possibilites?

Answer (score 3):

I am a system administrator and this sounds to me as a misunderstanding. From an administrator pov .NET is only a 'software library', it does nothing itself. The problem is what your applications do with .NET. So, does your application use some communication port? Does your application write some log on the file system? Where? How big they are? Retention needed [YES]? Does your application require some privileged account to run or not? Which privileges? Does they need to access external resources, a database, a file share, active directory? How much processor time/memory/disk capacity/disk iops they need? How do I install/remove/start/stop it?

Administrators really need these informations to keep things running fine. Also developers need to think to these informations when writing code. And please, optimize it, avoid administrator user, C:\Windows or C:\ is not a good place to store stuff and Windows Update is not that bad thing :-))